# Samples: BookStore-MongoDB Does the Book ID exist in the MongoDB?

Tags: abp

I've just come across the abp framework and I have a question that I'd like to ask during the learning process.

I'm looking at this document Book Store: Angular UI & MongoDB (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Tutorials/Part-1?UI=NG&DB=Mongo)
The function is created and he works smoothly.

But the id that get from API (/api/app/book) I couldn't find in MongoDB.

I would like to know where the id is stored, or
Is he acting according to the content of the data?
Get Id From MongoDB:
[image: Get Id From MongoDB]

Get Id From API:
[image: Get Id From API]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the problem is not caused by the ABP framework.

HttpApi.Host then get data from /api/app/book:
[image: HttpApi.Host then get data from /api/app/book]

Using mongodb client and select the collection(Books):
[image: Using mongodb client and select the collection(Books)]

The step I took for the solution:
[image: The step I took for the solution]

This shows us that the problem is encoding/decoding.

Comment: thank you very much! I forgot to add your answer here.

[issue on github](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/4827)、    
[Detailed reasons for the problem](https://studio3t.com/knowledge-base/articles/mongodb-best-practices-uuid-data/)